# cakePHP - calendar plugin question

Tags: php, cakephp

im currently working on creating a small application for a website i'm working on the calendar im using is in the cakephp plugins folder. I have to display events depending on the city or view id i want the url like this.

http://imstillreallybored.com/cupload/full_calendar/cities/1

i also want to load the event model and not have load a 'cities' database table i already have all the information i need in two tables events and event_locations i just need to run a condition to get events according to the id. here the original link

http://imstillreallybored.com/cupload/full_calendar/

Answer (score 0):

This could be accomplished with a route.

```
Router::connect(
    '/full_calendar/cities/*',
    array(
       'plugin' => 'full_calendar',
       'controller' => 'events',
       'action' => 'view'
    )
);
```

That would match the /full_calendar/cities/[id] and the id would be passed in as the first parameter for the EventsController::view() action.

```
public function view($id = null) {
    // Your action logic
}
```

Comment: i'll have to try this how could a print a city's name like
/full_calendar/cities/sanDiego

Comment: after 'action' => 'view' add another element to the array which is urlencode($cityName). You'll need to urlencode() it so that spaces don't break the url. Then the $id in the controller action would be the city name. You'll just have to urldecode() it.